# post data not being recognized node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Here is my `index.js` file...

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'QChat' });
});
router.post('/login', function(req, res) {
  console.log("processing");
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});
module.exports = router;
```

And here is the code I am using to stored POST data into my mongoDB database. This is located in my `app.js` file...

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user');
var db = mongoose.connection;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {
    console.log("connected");
    var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
        mail    : String
    });
    var User = mongoose.model('emp', Schema);
    app.post('/login', function(request, response){
        console.log("here");
        new User({
            mail: request.body.email
        }).save(function(err, doc) {
        if (err)
            res.json(err);
        else 
            console.log('save user successfully...');
        });
    });
```

Code works fine up until it reaches the `app.post`, after that it does not seem to read the rest of the code.

I know my `index.js` file works because when I submit the form, I get to a page that displays `respond with a resource` (because of the send function). But for some reason, `app.post` is not being read, am I missing something?

Here is my jade html to show that I am implementing everything correctly...

```
form(class="inputs", action="/login", method="post")
  input(type="text", name="email",class="form-control", id="emailLogin", placeholder="Queen's Email")
  input(type="submit",name = "homePage" class ="loginButton" value="Log In" id="loginButton")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try to move the following code out of `db.once('open')`

```
db.on('error', console.error);
db.once('open', function() {});

app.post('/login', function(request, response){
    console.log("here");
    new User({
        mail: request.body.email
    }).save(function(err, doc) {
    if (err)
        res.json(err);
    else 
        console.log('save user successfully...');
    });
});
```

Another issue in your code, please make sure the first parameter of `mongoose.model` is `User`, otherwise, one error could pop up.

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    mail    : String
});
var User = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```